# Running PhantomJS from a Spring applicatoin for webpage thumbnails

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, phantomjs

I have two choices for my usecase

1. The user submits a URL and I capture a screenshot of that webpage, save it in the db and render it as and when required

**OR**

1. Every time the server sends a list of URLs the browser generates screenshots of these URLs

For both cases i have considered using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). There are lot of examples of PhantomJS functions invoked from a console, but haven't found any on how to do it from the **server side** (java, except for [this](https://gist.github.com/1401944) which i couldn't get working(line #51, waits for socket connection)) or **clientside** (using javascript, which i think would be an overhead for the browser). It would be great if someone could help me.

I have thought about third party providers like [websnapr](http://www.websnapr.com/) but i don't know how reliable they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh! I never new it was this simple. It works with two lines of code:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process process = builder.start();
```

But i would like to have input on which one would be a better approach, server side or client side? And what are the over heads!

Comment: could you please provide a full code on how to use `PhantomJS` in a Spring webapp? At least in a controller?

Comment: Please add the code,as I am stuck on the same issue

Comment: I have discarded the project midway and don't have the code with me now. It was long back.